# Generating and saving code from Macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am analyzing a legacy code which heavily using macro, I am lost in understanding how macro are expanding in code.

Could any one suggest me some tool or technique so that I can study actual code generated from macro expansion.

Platform : Windows XP
Language : C++
Compiler : VC6

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. It is probably much worse after macro expansion.

Comment: @mmyers , I just want to understand how code is working , I am not going to change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With visual studio you can use the Generate Preprocessed File option.

In the properties for your project select

```
C/C++/Preprocessor/
```

In that tab there is an option to:

```
generate a preprocessed file.
```

Select Yes, with numbers.

Answer (score 6):

To run the GCC as a pre-processor only do:

```
gcc -E source-file.cc > processed-source-file.cc
```

It also do all the #includes that you may or may not want.

Comment: Dear Chen Levy , thank for writing, But my code is windows & VC6 based

Answer (score 4):

Run the pre-processor (cpp) on the source file.

Comment: Chen has shown how to do this using GCC. With VC, you need to pass `/i`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Visual C this doesn't help you, but it might be helpful to others to mention:

Netbeans 6.7 is able to display the macro expanded version of C/C++ code in a separate window during editing.

Comment: thanks i will try with Netbeans,  I wont compile but can edit using it :)